# How do I make it possible to scroll over an Image in Codename One?

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a `Codename` One App that has Images in it.

However, whenever I'm trying to scroll when the cursor is on the image it doesn't work.

**Edit:**

1: (Some Component) Scrolling works;

2: (Image) Scrolling doesn't work

Link is [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJQvr.png)

```
Image img = Image.createImage(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(i.getImagePath()));
imgViewer.setImage(img);
imgViewer.setHeight(img.getHeight());
imgViewer.setFocusable(false);
```

This is the code that creates the `ImageView`.

The Image View is inside a Container which has the Layout `BoxLayoutY` (vertically scrollable)
That Container is in the Form which is the most bottom Layer, also set to `BoxLayoutY`

I suppose there must be some function that I can call to make it possible to scroll when the cursor is on an image, but I have no idea, which one that is.

Comment: Just share your code and try to explain better the issue.

Comment: I am not Codename One dev so can't help you by answering your question, but let me help you improve your question so others who would be able to answer it can do it easier. Try to explain ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Are you getting compilation error; runtime exception; other behavior which differs from what you expected? Also how does your code look like? (Please limit it to [mcve] - so it wouldn't contain parts unrelated to task you are asking about)?

Comment: You need to post more code, in particular concerning the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ImageViewer` use `Label` or `ScaleImageLabel`. `ImageViewer` grabs your pointer events to pan the image and allows zooming into it. It's designed for use over the entire `Form` and won't work well in a scrolling scenario.

If you want that functionality I suggest putting a small thumbnail in a `Button` then when it's clicked show the `ImageViewer` in a separate `Form` at the center of a `BorderLayout`.